# Why does typescript think my type is an array when it clear isn't?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a fragment

```
export type MyFragment = {
  __typename?: "MyFragment"
  age: string
  friends?: Array<{
    id: string
  }> | null
}
```

But when I export this type like so:

`type Friends = MyFragment["friends"]`

and then use it

```
const MyComponent = (friends: Friends) => {
  return (
    {friends.map(friend) => <div>{friend.id}</div>}
  )
}
```

it says `id` does not exist on `friend` and when I hover over friend it thinks it's an array and lists out all array options

Comment: Is it a runtime error or a TypeScript error?

Comment: @vr. compilation error

Comment: [ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCyiBiUCGBzAW2ADt4BeOAbwCg44B9epFYnIgfgC44AiDbfEVI9acfMG4BnGFACWxPKIBmckgBNJXOAEEouRAB4adOrLVSZ8xXQC+APjgAfOMQCuAG3fUb1as1TYsuqScBT8uIQkMADaPCpBxBo8ALq+AMYQxNLoiADCEASQxFGhcAAU8cHcgcEAlKEOxnBQwDCuUMRwlYmaAHQEOGBlFaqJ9WQO3Wq9ZrWi3kA)

Comment: Your code is not even valid syntax. Could you fix the post first?

Comment: When I "fix" your code (making assumptions), I get an entirely different error: https://tsplay.dev/NdE0Mm

Comment: Because you're saying `friends` can be null. `null` isn't an array.

Comment: @AKX that might be it. is there a way for me to say it has to be array without touching that original fragment? Can I somehow omit undefined null and say in my new type it HAS to be an array

Comment: Is your post showing the wrong error then?

Comment: You said it could be undefined, array of objects or null and then you expect it to be an array of objects.

Make up your mind :) either check if is it an array of objects (or at least array) before assuming it is or fix the type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To [simplify your issue](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiBiAnAhgcwLYQHbCgXigG8AoKKAM0QEtsATAZwH4AuKAQURRAB4SyyqtVvWDUsqUlAC+APigAfKFgCuAG1XEpxUJChIaWBvlgIUGbMADaAIkoGG1gLrFi5ZVgDGwKgHssFAAo7OnpWfRCASiJJRAhgZUR-YMN6ADp0ZDAg-DlyVMEIgG5NYiA):

```
type MyFragment = {
  friends?: Array<{
    id: string
  }> | null
}
type Friends = MyFragment["friends"]

function f(friends: Friends) {
  return friends.map(f => f.id);
}
```

You're saying `MyFragment.friends`, i.e. the type `Friends` can be

- an array of `{id: string}`s,
- `undefined` (via the `?`),
- or `null` (via `| null`)

If the value is `undefined` or `null`, you can't map over it, hence a type error for the union type of an array, undefined or null.

If you want an empty array at runtime, do so using nullish coalescing:

```
(friends ?? []).map(f => f.id)
```

Alternately, to make the `Friends` type alias never `null` or `undefined`, use the [`NonNullable` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype):

```
type Friends = NonNullable<MyFragment["friends"]>;
```

Then you don't need to change the function/component (but naturally, you also can't pass in `null` or `undefined` to a function that expects a `NonNullable` `Friends`).

Comment: typeof MyFragment["friends"][0]?

Comment: @DanteTheSmith `Property '0' does not exist on type '{ id: string; }[] | null | undefined'`.

Comment: I know I was hinting that if he tries that which by his logic should work it becomes obvious much more obvious where is the problem. It says you there is no 0 on type which can be null or undefined. This would be much clearer to read than what he initially got as an TS error.